# Ios webview calling javascript function wont work

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

My objective-c code looks like this:

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"testFunction(%@)", details.name];

NSString *userName = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:test];
NSLog(@"Web response: %@",test);
```

This prints out `testFunction(the string of details.name here)`.

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(title);</script>

var title;

function testFunction(var) {
    title = var;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS you closed the script tag in the first line leaving  out the function

your JS should look like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(title);

var title;

function testFunction(var) {
    title = var;
}
</script>
```